# Identifier expected al llamar un método

Tags: java

Buena noches, describo rápidamente mi programa antes de explicar el problema, cuenta con 4 clases:
**Character**
**Army** : Almacena un número de Character en una matriz.
**Bot** : Usa una Army anterior de la que se escoge un Character y lo hace combatir contra otro Character aleatorio (que no pertenece a la anterior Army)
**Main** : Elige la opción que se quiere tomar

Una vez están prácticamente todos los métodos hechos, después de crear el Army que he mencionado anteriormente en la clase Bot, cuando intento aplicar un método que se encarga de llenarla de Character me aparece el error **< identifier > expected**
Tan solo he escrito esto:

```
private Army userArmy = new Army ();  
userArmy.setCharacters();      //<----- Me marca el error aquí
```

¿A qué se debe este error? Que yo sepa no me he dejado ningún paréntesis ni ; o . que pueda afectar en la llamada. Por si de caso os dejo el método al que llamo a continuación:

```
    public void setCharacters(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            characters[i][j] = new Character((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(3)));
        }
    }
    characters[3][0] = new Character((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(3)));

       /* Up to this it has created the first 13 random characters.
       / Later, we add the dragons:
       */

    int numDragons = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(3));
    for (int i = 1; i < 1 + numDragons; i++){
        characters[3][i] = new Character();
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mete `userArmy.setCharacters();      //<----- Me marca el error aquí` en el constructor de la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, así hice y funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes hacer uso de una variable global directamente en el cuerpo de una clase, debes hacerlo dentro del contructor, dentro de un método o bloque de inicialización para este ultimo seria así:

```
private Army userArmy = new Army ();  
{
userArmy.setCharacters(); 
}
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, se me ha ido la cabeza y parece que no me he fijado ni en que hacía. Tanto tiempo buscando el fallo para tenerlo delante. En fin, muchas gracias.

Comment: @AntonioM Stackoverflow no es un foro, por lo tanto, de nada sirve editar el título de la pregunta poniéndole `[Resuelta]`. Lo que indica que la pregunta está resulta, **es activar el cotejo que aparece a la izquierda de la respuesta dada que haya resuelto el problema**.

Comment: Si la respuesta ha sido de ayuda, no olvides votar por esta.